# cURL base64_encode XML

Tags: php, curl, asp.net-web-api, base64

I am trying to cURL a base64_encoded xml string to a c# WebAPI that i dont have control over. I can cURL the string successfully but it is not being accepted by the API.

Logging the output shows that cURL is stripping + characters from the base64 string which i believe to be the problem.

The code i have is:

```
$username = "username";
$password = "$23hrlkbl";
$xml = "<Envelope><Header><User>".$username."</User><Password>".$password."</Password></Header></Envelope>";

$passThru = "https://api.domain.com/SignIn.aspx?passthruUrl=/Management/Api/DataEnrichment/GetAddresses/?buildingNumber=1%26streetName=Nightingale%20Road%26postcode=L12%200QN
$post_packet_data = 'XMLdataPacket='.urlencode(base64_encode($xml));

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $passThru);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_packet_data);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);

$response = curl_exec ($ch);
curl_close($ch);
print_r($response);
```

Posting the following string (non urlencoded $post_packet_data) via an html form to the $passThru address works successfully

```
XMLdataPacket=PEVudmVsb3BlPjxIZWFkZXI+PFVzZXI+dXNlcm5hbWU8L1VzZXI+PFBhc3N3b3JkPiQyM2hybGtibDwvUGFzc3dvcmQ+PC9IZWFkZXI+PC9FbnZlbG9wZT4=
```

However when posting the same string via cURL the following is sent and not accepted

```
XMLdataPacket=PEVudmVsb3BlPjxIZWFkZXI PFVzZXI dXNlcm5hbWU8L1VzZXI PFBhc3N3b3JkPiQyM2hybGtibDwvUGFzc3dvcmQ PC9IZWFkZXI PC9FbnZlbG9wZT4=
```

**UPDATE**

After speaking to the developers of the API they have confirmed the requests are now coming in in the correct format but believe the calls are not being processed due to incorrect headers being sent. They have sent me the headers of a working call which they got using fiddler:

```
POST https://api.domain.com/SignIn.aspx?passthruUrl=/Management/Api/DataEnrichment/GetAddresses/?buildingNumber=1%26streetName=Nightingale%20Road%26postcode=L12%200QN HTTP/1.1
Host: test.domain.com
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 164
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
Origin: null
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/33.0.1750.146 Safari/537.36
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language: en-GB,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.6
Cookie: ASP.NET_SessionId=uzwfjq3zojao3l5fw141l453

XMLdataPacket=PEVudmVsb3BlPjxIZWFkZXI%2BPFVzZXI+dXNlcm5hbWU8L1VzZXI%2BPFBhc3N3b3JkPiQyM2hybGtibDwvUGFzc3dvcmQ%2BPC9IZWFkZXI%2BPC9FbnZlbG9wZT4%3D
```

How would i amend the headers of the cURL call to replicate the above. Currently again using fiddler the cURL call headers appear as the following:

```
GET http://test.domain.com/test_call.php HTTP/1.1
Host: test.domain.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; rv:27.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/27.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-gb,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Cookie: CAKEPHP=g22d7kf7qs8b1v02uui2mnop30
Authorization: Basic bmV0aG91c2VwcmljZXMxOnRlbXAxODkx
Connection: keep-alive
Cache-Control: max-age=0
```

The data is receieved at the api end as POST but the curl headers are coming through as GET according to the above

Comment: Another suggestion is try this: `$post_packet_data = http_build_query(array('XMLdataPacket' => base64_encode($bym_header)), null, '&');` This will take care of the URL encoding

Comment: This does make the outputted POST data from cURL look the same as that from the HTML form but the API still rejects it. Could it be something to do with the POST type or incorrect headers being sent?

Comment: You should be getting back some error message, can you post that? Probably it has to do with headers since you mention it works if you post via a form. What kind of API is it? Is it by any chance SOAP?

Comment: Yes it is a SOAP API, written in c# .net i believe. There are not any errors returned unfortunately, if the call is successful then XML is returned if unsuccessful then it redirects to a login page so i get the HTML for that returned.

Comment: I don't think the issue is in your cURL request but in the SOAP client. Is it a public API where we can see the WSDL?

Comment: unfortuantely its not a public API so i cant post the WSDL, not very helpful i know

Comment: Can you maybe show how you're using the SOAP client? And remove the sensitive parts of course. My guess somewhere along those lines you have an issue. But since the WSDL is not available not much help that we can give you.

Comment: Sorry for any confusion with this but it turns out now that the API is not SOAP but rather a .net WebApi. From what i can see this is a Microsoft RESTfull API

Comment: It shouldn't matter what the API server is written in. Is more important what kind of protocol they use to communicate. So do they accept SOAP, HTTP or something else?

Comment: They accept HTTP not SOAP.

Comment: then it should be pretty easy with CURL. But there are plenty of wrappers out there for CURL and will make your life easier. Don't reinvent the wheel.

Answer (score 2):

Try using rawurlencode() instead of urlencode() - it encodes the space character using '%20' instead of using the '+' character.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesnt seem to help. Looking at the logs the POST data outputted from cURL now looks the same as the outputted data from the form post but the call to the API via cURL is still rejected.